# JSON stringify fails only when data comes from looped GET request

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, get

So I am having an issues when I am trying to create a JSON string. I only have issues when the data I am using to build the object/array that will be stringified comes from a GET request in a loop.

When I post the actual javascript object to the console it contains all the correct information. but fails to produce a valid JSON string. I have tested this method (examples below) and know it works. I have come to the conclusion that it has to do with the GET requests. I have tried a few solutions; played with variable scope, async flow control, and still no luck. Hence me being here. What am I missing?

Thanks all

Here is the code with issues:

```
 var start = 1518;
var end = 1522;
var eventList = {};
eventList['event'] = [];

for (var i = 0; i < (end - start); i++) {
  $.get('https://www.someaddress.com/events/index.php?view=' + (start + i), function(response) {

    var eventRep = $(response).find('h2').text();
    var categoryRep = $(response).find('span.center-name').text();
    var descriptionRep = $(response).find('div.description.col-md-9').find('p').text();

    var eventScrape = {
      "title": eventRep,
      "category": categoryRep,
      "description": descriptionRep
    };
    //alert(eventRep); 
    eventList['event'].push(eventScrape);
  });
}

var str = JSON.stringify(eventList, undefined, 4);
console.log(eventList);
console.log(str);
```

Failed JSON produced:

```
    {
    "event": []
}
```

Here is a working example of what I want:

```
  var eventList = {};
  eventList['event'] = [];


  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var eventRep = "Event title " + i;
    var categoryRep = "Event category " + i;
    var descriptionRep = "Event description " + i;

    var eventScrape = {
      "title": eventRep,
      "category": categoryRep,
      "description": descriptionRep
    };

    eventList['event'].push(eventScrape);
    //alert(i);
  }

  var str = JSON.stringify(eventList, undefined, 4);
  console.log(eventList);
  console.log(str);
```

JSON produced by example:

```
{  
   "event":[  
      {  
         "title":"Event title 0",
         "category":"Event category 0",
         "description":"Event description 0"
      },
      {  
         "title":"Event title 1",
         "category":"Event category 1",
         "description":"Event description 1"
      },
      {  
         "title":"Event title 2",
         "category":"Event category 2",
         "description":"Event description 2"
      },
      {  
         "title":"Event title 3",
         "category":"Event category 3",
         "description":"Event description 3"
      },
      {  
         "title":"Event title 4",
         "category":"Event category 4",
         "description":"Event description 4"
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.get` is executed is async manner so put your code inside `get` function

Solution code

```js
var start = 1518;
var end = 1522;
var eventList = {};
eventList['event'] = [];

for (var i = 0; i < (end - start); i++) {
  $.get('https://www.someaddress.com/events/index.php?view=' + (start + i), function(response) {

    var eventRep = $(response).find('h2').text();
    var categoryRep = $(response).find('span.center-name').text();
    var descriptionRep = $(response).find('div.description.col-md-9').find('p').text();

    var eventScrape = {
      "title": eventRep,
      "category": categoryRep,
      "description": descriptionRep
    };
    //alert(eventRep); 
    eventList['event'].push(eventScrape);

    //as $.get is async data will be loaded in async manner so you cannot access it unless it is available
    var str = JSON.stringify(eventList, undefined, 4);
    console.log(eventList);
    console.log(str);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, greatly appreciated. Makes sense now, knew I must have been overlooking something. Was driving me a bit bonkers.